# Can I disable logging 404 errors in my craft.log file?

Tags: error, 404, logging, timeout

I want to get a better understanding of some issues in production surrounding timeouts but as its a high traffic site the craft logs get replaced about every 15 minutes due to the amount of 404's that are requested.

Most are stuff like missing apple-touch-icons or old images from our last version of the site that are now gone. Is there any way to tell craft either to not log those 404s so that craft.log becomes a little more useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, but I agree it's kind of annoying.

I thought maybe you could pull it off with a plugin since Yii does have an [onException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onException-detail) event, but there wouldn't be a way to disable logging of 404's without some code changes on our end.

I've added it to our 3.0 list to add a config setting to disable logging of 404's though.

Comment: Cool! Yeah that would be great. I guess I'll just compile a list of the more popular 404's an manually resolve for now! Craft 3.0 is going to be a good 'un, I feel!

Comment: I look forward to this! Currently it's very hard to debug stuck "cache cleaning" tasks since the logs are full of 404s...